# SSRS Reports Missing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When navigating to https://servername/reports/browse an entire folders worth of reports is missing.  I have restored a backup of the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases that contain these reports.  The application that executes the report is able to sucessfully run the report confirming that it is there however when I go to https://servername/reports/browse or https://servername/reportserver the folder isn't listed there.  I need to get into that to fix some permissions errors.  What can I do to restore the report server so that it properly displays the folder structure?  I have tried restarting the services as well as the entire server.

Comment: How did the permissions change?

Comment: I assume you've tried clicking "Details View"?

Comment: It the folder hidden?  You can display hidden folders under the Tiles menu; "Show hidden items".

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of digging I found the reports.  They were moved to another folder.  Still trying to figure out who did it but at least I've got the information and was able to fix the problem.